# autolayout content hugging on UIImageView when image is nil?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I want to place a UIImageView to the left of a UILabel.  The image may sometimes be nil, in which case I want it to take 0 horizontal spacing.  I've tried a variety of content hugging/compression settings, but the image view hogs all the space if it's image is nil.

|[imageView][label]|

What can I do that doesn't involve overloading or changing constraints?  Right now I'm looking at making a 0 pixel image, and that works.

Comment: what happens if you tell the image view to size to fit content?

Comment: You mean call sizeToFit?  I shouldn't have to do that with autolayout, should I?

Comment: I mean to select the image view in IB and in the menu bar click Editor -> Size to Fit Content

Comment: This is all dynamic - I don't know what content will be there - and I'm not using IB.